# Tomcat partial startup on linux

Tags: centos, tomcat, java

My server: CentOs 6 64-bit.
Installed jre by downloading Linux x64 (64-bit) jre rpm 
and used command `rpm -Uvh myJreFileName.rpm`

Installed tomcat6 with yum and then tomcat7 without yum to see if my problem was with tomcat6 but it was not.

When I startup tomcat 7 it says:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Every time it starts it seems to fail at a different time. Sometimes it will not even get to taking ports. Sometimes catalina.out shows it gets to deploying first application.

When I try to open **myDomain:8080** it is just waiting for something and will stop when I kill my tomcat process.

Before renting this VPS I tried the same environment setup with my 32-bit computer and I did not have any problems like this. Don't know what I have done wrong this time.

Some catalina.out samples after starting and killing:

```
May 06, 2012 3:45:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
May 06, 2012 3:45:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2012 3:45:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 06, 2012 3:45:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2630 ms
May 06, 2012 3:45:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 06, 2012 3:45:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
May 06, 2012 3:45:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/examples


May 06, 2012 11:26:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib


May 06, 2012 11:27:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb178a8adf0, pid=3236, tid=140400067479296
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x72edf0]  ObjectMonitor::UnlinkAfterAcquire(Thread*, ObjectWaiter*)+0x50
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/core or core.3236


May 06, 2012 11:28:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
May 06, 2012 11:28:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2012 11:28:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 06, 2012 11:28:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1305 ms

May 06, 2012 11:29:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Edit: hs_err_pid3956.log (trimmed because of max post length)

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8eecd09df0, pid=3956, tid=140251689252608
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x72edf0]  ObjectMonitor::UnlinkAfterAcquire(Thread*, ObjectWaiter*)+0x50

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f8ee808f800):  JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3960, stack(0x00007f8ee40df000,0x00007f8ee41e0000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f8ee41de510, RCX=0x00007f8ed8003590, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007f8ee41de4d0, RBP=0x00007f8ee41de4e0, RSI=0x00007f8ee808f800, RDI=0x00007f8ed8003578
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007f8ee41de328, R10=0x0000000000000002, R11=0x00007f8ee41de648
R12=0x00007f8ed8003578, R13=0x00007f8eed2c9c00, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x00007f8eed2c62e8
RIP=0x00007f8eecd09df0, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f8ee41de4d0)
0x00007f8ee41de4d0:   00007f8ed8003578 00007f8ee808f800
0x00007f8ee41de4e0:   00007f8ee41de570 00007f8eecd0b187
0x00007f8ee41de4f0:   00007f8ee41de520 00007f8ed80035c0
...


Instructions: (pc=0x00007f8eecd09df0)
0x00007f8eecd09dd0:   dc 00 00 00 48 39 c3 90 0f 84 d2 00 00 00 66 90
0x00007f8eecd09de0:   48 89 c2 48 8b 00 48 85 c0 74 05 48 39 c3 75 f0
0x00007f8eecd09df0:   48 8b 00 48 89 02 48 c7 43 08 ad 0b 00 00 48 c7
0x00007f8eecd09e00:   03 ad 0b 00 00 c7 43 24 02 00 00 00 5b 41 5c c9 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f8ee41de510 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ee808f800
RCX=0x00007f8ed8003590 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f8ee41de4d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ee808f800
RBP=0x00007f8ee41de4e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ee808f800
RSI=0x00007f8ee808f800 is a thread
RDI=0x00007f8ed8003578 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f8ee41de328 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ee808f800
R10=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f8ee41de648 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ee808f800
R12=0x00007f8ed8003578 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007f8eed2c9c00: <offset 0xceec00> in /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f8eec5db000
R14=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f8eed2c62e8: <offset 0xceb2e8> in /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f8eec5db000


Stack: [0x00007f8ee40df000,0x00007f8ee41e0000],  sp=0x00007f8ee41de4d0,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x72edf0]  ObjectMonitor::UnlinkAfterAcquire(Thread*, ObjectWaiter*)+0x50
V  [libjvm.so+0x730187]  ObjectMonitor::EnterI(Thread*)+0x287
V  [libjvm.so+0x731087]  ObjectMonitor::enter(Thread*)+0x1c7
V  [libjvm.so+0x54561d]  InterpreterRuntime::monitorenter(JavaThread*, BasicObjectLock*)+0x9d
j  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(J)Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;+23
j  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;+2
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x54df25]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x355
V  [libjvm.so+0x54ca48]  JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x28
V  [libjvm.so+0x54ccdc]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x17c
V  [libjvm.so+0x54ce07]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*)+0x47
V  [libjvm.so+0x5a6e3f]  thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*)+0xdf
V  [libjvm.so+0x860228]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xc8
V  [libjvm.so+0x860378]  JavaThread::run()+0x138
V  [libjvm.so+0x741ff0]  java_start(Thread*)+0x100

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(J)Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;+23
j  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;+2
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f8ee8677800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3966, stack(0x00007f8ed1536000,0x00007f8ed1637000)]
  0x00007f8ee80de800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3964, stack(0x00007f8ed1d6b000,0x00007f8ed1e6c000)]
  0x00007f8ee80dc000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3963, stack(0x00007f8ed1e6c000,0x00007f8ed1f6d000)]
  0x00007f8ee80da000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3962, stack(0x00007f8ed1f6d000,0x00007f8ed206e000)]
  0x00007f8ee80d7800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3961, stack(0x00007f8ed206e000,0x00007f8ed216f000)]
=>0x00007f8ee808f800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3960, stack(0x00007f8ee40df000,0x00007f8ee41e0000)]
  0x00007f8ee808d000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3959, stack(0x00007f8ee41e0000,0x00007f8ee42e1000)]
  0x00007f8ee8008000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3957, stack(0x00007f8eeddd1000,0x00007f8eeded2000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f8ee8085800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f8ee42e1000,0x00007f8ee43e2000] [id=3958]
  0x00007f8ee80e9800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f8ed1c6a000,0x00007f8ed1d6b000] [id=3965]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4992K, used 84K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf760000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4480K,   1% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf215128, 0x00000000cf660000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf660000, 0x00000000cf660000, 0x00000000cf6e0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf6e0000, 0x00000000cf6e0000, 0x00000000cf760000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3938K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,  35% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddf28a38, 0x00000000ddf28c00, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 9151K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  43% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb6efd38, 0x00000000fb6efe00, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x00007f8ee479c000, 0x00007f8ee4a0c000, 0x00007f8ee779c000)
 total_blobs=341 nmethods=73 adapters=221 free_code_cache=48511Kb largest_free_block=49647808

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.156 Thread 0x00007f8ee80da000 nmethod 66 0x00007f8ee48093d0 code [0x00007f8ee4809520, 0x00007f8ee48096b8]
Event: 1.168 Thread 0x00007f8ee80dc000 nmethod 63 0x00007f8ee483aa90 code [0x00007f8ee483b2c0, 0x00007f8ee483ee00]
Event: 1.178 Thread 0x00007f8ee80da000   67             java.util.HashMap::indexFor (6 bytes)
Event: 1.178 Thread 0x00007f8ee80da000 nmethod 67 0x00007f8ee4823a50 code [0x00007f8ee4823b80, 0x00007f8ee4823bb8]
Event: 1.186 Thread 0x00007f8ee80dc000   68             java.util.HashMap::hash (23 bytes)
Event: 1.187 Thread 0x00007f8ee80dc000 nmethod 68 0x00007f8ee48091d0 code [0x00007f8ee4809300, 0x00007f8ee4809358]
Event: 1.199 Thread 0x00007f8ee80da000   69             sun.misc.MetaIndex::mayContain (51 bytes)
Event: 1.233 Thread 0x00007f8ee80da000 nmethod 69 0x00007f8ee4826710 code [0x00007f8ee4826860, 0x00007f8ee4826b68]
Event: 1.236 Thread 0x00007f8ee80dc000   70             java.lang.String::indexOf (7 bytes)
Event: 1.238 Thread 0x00007f8ee80dc000 nmethod 70 0x00007f8ee4826290 code [0x00007f8ee48263e0, 0x00007f8ee4826548]

GC Heap History (8 events):
Event: 0.338 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4416K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf750000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf6d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf750000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddb50200, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6343K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  29% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb431d90, 0x00000000fb431e00, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 0.344 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 511K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf750000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf650000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf74fff8, 0x00000000cf750000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf6d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1091K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,   9% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddc60fa0, 0x00000000ddc61000, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6343K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  29% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb431d90, 0x00000000fb431e00, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 0.842 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4927K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf750000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf74fff8, 0x00000000cf750000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf6d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1091K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,   9% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddc60fa0, 0x00000000ddc61000, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6838K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  32% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4adad8, 0x00000000fb4adc00, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 0.848 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 511K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf750000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf650000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf6cfff8, 0x00000000cf6d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf750000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1928K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,  17% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddd32220, 0x00000000ddd32400, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6838K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  32% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4adad8, 0x00000000fb4adc00, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 1.157 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4927K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf750000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf6cfff8, 0x00000000cf6d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf750000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1928K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,  17% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000ddd32220, 0x00000000ddd32400, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 8151K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  38% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb5f5f90, 0x00000000fb5f6000, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 1.165 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 511K [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf750000, 0x00000000ddb50000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf200000, 0x00000000cf650000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x00000000cf6d0000, 0x00000000cf74fff8, 0x00000000cf750000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf650000, 0x00000000cf6d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 2946K [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000de600000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10944K,  26% used [0x00000000ddb50000, 0x00000000dde30bd8, 0x00000000dde30c00, 0x00000000de600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 8151K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  38% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb5f5f90, 0x00000000fb5f6000, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}   

Deoptimization events (6 events):
Event: 0.931 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x00007f8ee482df5c
Event: 0.932 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x00007f8ee481faf8
Event: 1.038 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00007f8ee48068f0
Event: 1.049 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00007f8ee48068f0
Event: 1.050 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00007f8ee48068f0
Event: 1.243 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x00007f8ee48205e0

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 1.238 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf399050 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.239 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3a1a98 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.239 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3a2138 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.239 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3b0660 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.239 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3b0dd0 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.239 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3b39a0 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.240 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3b40f0 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.240 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3b9608 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.240 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Threw 0x00000000cf3b9dc8 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 1.243 Thread 0x00007f8ee8008000 Implicit null exception at 0x00007f8ee4820265 to 0x00007f8ee48205cd

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.250 loading class 0x00007f8ee86750e0 done
Event: 1.250 loading class 0x00007f8ee8677690
Event: 1.250 loading class 0x00007f8ee8677690 done
Event: 1.250 Thread 0x00007f8ee8677800 Thread added: 0x00007f8ee8677800
Event: 1.250 loading class 0x00007f8ee8678f80
Event: 1.250 loading class 0x00007f8ee8678f80 done
Event: 1.250 loading class 0x00007f8ee8679150
Event: 1.250 Executing VM operation: GenCollectFull
Event: 1.279 Executing VM operation: GenCollectFull done
Event: 1.279 loading class 0x00007f8ee8679150 done


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 245334094                          /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 90:77 245334094                          /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/bin/java
00601000-00622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
cf200000-cf760000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
cf760000-ddb50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ddb50000-de600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
de600000-fae00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
fae00000-fc2c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
fc2c0000-100000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ebc000000-7f8ebc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ebc021000-7f8ec0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ec4000000-7f8ec43a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ec43a8000-7f8ec8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ec8000000-7f8ec8599000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ec8599000-7f8ecc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ecc000000-7f8ecc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ecc021000-7f8ed0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed13fd000-7f8ed1536000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1536000-7f8ed1539000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1539000-7f8ed1637000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1637000-7f8ed163f000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 245334212                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
7f8ed163f000-7f8ed183e000 ---p 00008000 90:77 245334212                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
7f8ed183e000-7f8ed183f000 rw-p 00007000 90:77 245334212                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
7f8ed183f000-7f8ed1854000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 245334216                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7f8ed1854000-7f8ed1a54000 ---p 00015000 90:77 245334216                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7f8ed1a54000-7f8ed1a55000 rw-p 00015000 90:77 245334216                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7f8ed1a55000-7f8ed1a65000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 245334218                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7f8ed1a65000-7f8ed1c65000 ---p 00010000 90:77 245334218                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7f8ed1c65000-7f8ed1c66000 rw-p 00010000 90:77 245334218                  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7f8ed1c66000-7f8ed1c68000 r--s 00008000 90:77 245303774                  /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
7f8ed1c68000-7f8ed1c69000 r--s 00005000 90:77 245303760                  /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/commons-daemon.jar
7f8ed1c69000-7f8ed1c6a000 r--s 00006000 90:77 245303752                  /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar
7f8ed1c6a000-7f8ed1c6b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1c6b000-7f8ed1d6b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1d6b000-7f8ed1d6e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1d6e000-7f8ed1e6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1e6c000-7f8ed1e6f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1e6f000-7f8ed1f6d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1f6d000-7f8ed1f70000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed1f70000-7f8ed206e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed206e000-7f8ed2071000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed2071000-7f8ed216f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed216f000-7f8ed8000000 r--p 00000000 90:77 244390728                  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive-rpm
7f8ed8000000-7f8ed8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ed8021000-7f8edc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8edc000000-7f8edc0c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8edc0c3000-7f8ee0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ee0000000-7f8ee0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ee0021000-7f8ee4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ee40ad000-7f8ee40b0000 r--s 00018000 90:77 245334628                  
7f8eed2bf000-7f8eed2fa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eed2fa000-7f8eed480000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 244389970                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f8eed480000-7f8eed680000 ---p 00186000 90:77 244389970                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f8eed680000-7f8eed684000 r--p 00186000 90:77 244389970                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f8eed684000-7f8eed685000 rw-p 0018a000 90:77 244389970                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f8eed685000-7f8eed68a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eed68a000-7f8eed68c000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 244389994                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f8eed68c000-7f8eed88c000 ---p 00002000 90:77 244389994                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f8eed88c000-7f8eed88d000 r--p 00002000 90:77 244389994                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f8eed88d000-7f8eed88e000 rw-p 00003000 90:77 244389994                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f8eedce1000-7f8eedd13000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eedd13000-7f8eeddc9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eeddc9000-7f8eeddd1000 rw-s 00000000 90:77 177799184                  /tmp/hsperfdata_root/3956
7f8eeddd1000-7f8eeddd4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eeddd4000-7f8eeded7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eeded7000-7f8eededa000 r--s 0001e000 90:77 245303786                  /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/catalina-ha.jar
7f8eededa000-7f8eededc000 r--s 0000b000 90:77 245303814                  /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
7f8eededc000-7f8eededd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eededd000-7f8eedede000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eedede000-7f8eededf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8eededf000-7f8eedee0000 r--p 0001f000 90:77 244384680                  /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7f8eedee0000-7f8eedee1000 rw-p 00020000 90:77 244384680                  /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7f8eedee1000-7f8eedee2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffdf69d000-7fffdf6b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffdf7fe000-7fffdf800000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xmx700M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/temp 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x8a0cb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x8a0cb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x73cf80], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

uname:Linux 2.6.32-042stab053.5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 27 11:42:17 MSD 2012 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.12 NPTL 2.12 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE infinity, NPROC 1024, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:0.19 0.08 0.01

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:          841200 kB
Cached:           130608 kB
Active:           184976 kB
Inactive:           4876 kB
Active(anon):      56776 kB
Inactive(anon):     2468 kB
Active(file):     128200 kB
Inactive(file):     2408 kB
Unevictable:           0
```

Comment: Did you build your own tomcat binaries or just got a pre-built copy (standalone version). You may need to check the compatibility of this version with your system.

Comment: I downloaded the tar file for tomcat7 and used yum install which installed tomcat6. I now also put a jetty server and I'm having same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Had someone take a look at my server and it seems there is not enough memory for tomcat.

Edit: Increased memory from 256MB to 1GB and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a JVM crash. Assuming you aren't running any native code then the root cause will be a JVM bug (or possibly a corrupted JVM).

Your options to fix this are:
- try re-installing the JVM
- install an earlier Java 7 release
- install the latest Java 6 release (Tomcat 7 will wort quite happily on Java 6)

To provide more information on exactly what is going wrong, we'd need to see the contents of /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/hs_err_pid3236.log